# Drupal 8 : Extend the block plugin and his annotation

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to extend the "Block" annotation. 
I would like to have a custom plugin block type with some additionnal annotations.  I know it's possible to make a block configurable (with the UI), but is it possible to customize an annotation and a plugin type ?

Actually, i try to :

- Extend the "Block" annotation
- Add my Block Manager
- Add a service for my block manager
- Extend the "BlockBase" abstract class

But it seems that my new type of block is not found. I guess i need to do something to tell Drupal : "That's my plugin type, and that's a block one".

Any ideas please ?

EDIT 06/11/2018 - i add some details :

Hi and thanks for your answer !

Sorry about that, i ve not some real code right now but my question was quite "theoretic" : is it possible to extend an annotation in Drupal 8 to add new attributes ? 
For example, with the [Block annotation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21Annotation%21Block.php/class/Block/8.2.x), is it possible to add new attributes to this annotation ?

For example, it should be something like :

```
class MyBlockAnnotation extends Block {
  public $myCustomAttribute = '';
}
```

And then, is it possible to use this new annotation in a new block type, extending [BlockBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21BlockBase.php/class/BlockBase/8.2.x) ?
Again, for example it should be something like that :

```
abstract class MyNewBlockType extends BlockBase {
  // My custom code here
  // With a $myCustomAttribute usage
}
```

After some research and several tests, it seems that is not really simple...

Regards,

Hervé

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We love to help you but unfortunately your question is still too vague. I guess it would help to see some of your code and to know your file's relative locations. Please update your question accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi and thanks, i just edit my question ;)